# Overload output operator in a enum in C++

Tags: c++

Its posible to overload the output operator inside an enum ? I'm getting all sort of errors(if I use class, I dont get any):

```
   ../src/oop.cpp:18:2: error: expected identifier before 'friend'
    ../src/oop.cpp:18:2: error: expected '}' before 'friend'
    ../src/oop.cpp:18:2: error: 'friend' used outside of class
    ../src/oop.cpp:18:16: error: expected initializer before '&' token
    ../src/oop.cpp:22:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
```

I'm after to implement something like this(java code):

```
public enum Type { 

  ACOUSTIC, ELECTRIC;

  public String toString() {
    switch(this) {
      case ACOUSTIC: return "acoustic";
      case ELECTRIC: return "electric";
      default:       return "unspecified";
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

edit:

```
enum Type {
    //ACOUSTIC, ELECTRIC;
    inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Type t) // error here
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: are you talking about .net or native c++? (And by the way, your default clause should better throw an exception!)

Comment: Im refering to native C++ yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
enum MyEnum {
  foo, bar
};

inline std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & Str, MyEnum V) {
  switch (V) {
  case foo: return Str << "foo";
  case bar: return Str << "bar";
  default: return Str << (int) V;
}
```

Comment: @vBx: See updated answer - you need the operator *outside* the enum.

Comment: ohh, that should have been obvios:) Thanky you, it works now.